# How to secure the old position of a list within a list for replacing it by a new one

Tags: java, list, for-loop, iterator, position

I've a list of lists with points(AWT)

```
List<List<Point>> listOfList = new ArrayList<List<Point>>();
```

now i'm iterating over it:

```
for (List<Point> list : listOfList) {
//...
//here i'm looking for a specific Point, if its inside, i add additional point 
//into the new listTemp
List<Point> tempList = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

i did it by copying all points into a new list"`tempList`".
Finally i replace the old list by the new.

```
listOfList.remove(list); 
listOfList.add(listTemp); 
}
```

Now my question is how can i secure that listTemp is taking exactly the old position of the deleted list within the listOfList?All of this is taking place in the for loop. So i don't want to iterate over the new added list.

Any idea?Thanks in advance

Comment: I feel the question should be more clear. what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm trying to insert a point into one of the list while i'm iterating over all lists. The task is not to have a look on this viewed list again while the iteration is still going on. The old list needs to be replaced by the new one in the position of the old, containing all old points+the new one

Comment: @Jürgen, you may add the new `Point` to the existing list as `list.add(newPoint)` if the list is mutable, rather than copying all the elements to the new list.

Comment: how do i know if its mutable?

Comment: @Jürgen, looks like you're creating `listOfList` as `new ArrayList<>` and populating in your program. So, it is mutable and you can simply add your new Point to the list without creating a new List. I am updating my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the `listOfLists` using a `ListIterator` and use `ListIterator.set()` to replace the list with a new one:

```
ListIterator<List<Point>> it = listOfList.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    List<Point> list = it.next();
    ...
    it.set(listTemp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After removing it, you can use

```
List.add(int index, E element)
```

to add the element at the wanted index

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Based on OP's latest comments, alternatively the new `Point` can be added to the specific list found rather than creating a new list and replacing the list found.

```
for (List<Point> list : listOfList) {
    if (list.contains(specificPoint) {
        //add new point to the same list. 
        list.add(newPoint);
    }
}
```

---

Keep the index of the `List` while looping over the `listOfList`. Therefore, you need to use old-style for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfList.size(); i++) {
    List<Point> list = listOfList.get(i);

    // ...
    // here i'm looking for a specific Point, if its inside, i add additional point
    // into the new listTemp
    if (list.contains(specificPoint)) {
        List<Point> tempList = new ArrayList<Point>();
        // populate tempList here.
        // ...
        // remove old list from the listOfList
        listOfList.remove(i);
        // insert new list to the same index.
        listOfList.add(i, tempList);
        break;
    }
}
```